# Check If image source contains value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image that changes on click and remains up for 2 seconds after the click.

This `IMG` `src` is changed with jQuery and after a `setTimeout` the source is returned. The issue is that if the user clicks a second time within those 2 seconds the source changes to an invalid location.

I am trying to prevent that from happening by checking if the current `src` of the image contains the value `_hover.png`:

```
if ('ThisIMG img[src*="_hover.png"]') {
    console.log("yes it does");
}
```

I have tried multiple methods in this if statement and I can't seem to get the correct argument.

Here are some of the different things I have tried:

```
$('.myImage').on({'click': function(){
        var ThisIMG = $(this);

        //if (ThisIMG.src == '_hover') {
        if ('ThisIMG img[src*="_hover.png"]') {
            console.log("yes it does");
        }
        //if (ThisIMG.attr("src").contains "_hover.png") {
        //  console.log('yes it does');
        //};

        // Method to change image source on click:
        var src = $(ThisIMG).attr("src").replace('.png', '_hover.png');
        $(ThisIMG).attr("src", src);
        console.log(src);

        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("in timeout");
            var src = $(ThisIMG).attr("src").replace("_hover.png", ".png");
            $(ThisIMG).attr("src", src);

        },1000);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<img class="myImage" src="graphics/1.png" />
```

Comment: Is that an unnecessary { next to click? shouldn't it be .on('click', function(){

Comment: @Dan good eye, replaced with `$('.tileImage').on("click",function() {` and removed the closing curly brace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the src and check for a substring using `indexOf()`:

```
if (ThisIMG.attr('src').indexOf('_hover.png') > -1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted but I've changed it so that what happens on the click of a button will not occur unless the src is equal to .png

```
if($('.myImage').attr('src') == '.png')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jwYE8/